# Mi registro no funciona en Microsoft Edge, ni en Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jquery, navegador-web

Tengo una página web que valora las tecnologías. Estoy recibiendo correos de que el registro no se puede hacer:

El registro cuenta con 3 pasos (esto lo hago con bootzard wizard). El primer paso corresponde a los datos personales de los futuros usuarios. El problema es cuando quieren pasar a la siguiente sección, que el jQuery no funciona.

```js
function scroll_to_class(element_class, removed_height) {
  var scroll_to = $(element_class).offset().top - removed_height;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() != scroll_to) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: scroll_to
    }, 0);
  }
}

function bar_progress(progress_line_object, direction) {
  var number_of_steps = progress_line_object.data('number-of-steps');
  var now_value = progress_line_object.data('now-value');
  var new_value = 0;
  if (direction == 'right') {
    new_value = now_value + (100 / number_of_steps);
  } else if (direction == 'left') {
    new_value = now_value - (100 / number_of_steps);
  }
  progress_line_object.attr('style', 'width: ' + new_value + '%;').data('now-value', new_value);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var correo_i = false;

  $(document).on("click", "#pertenece_sena", function(e) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      $("#contenido_preguntas").html('');
      $("#institucion_correo").append('<label class="sr-only" for="f1-institucional">Correo electr&oacute;nico insitucional</label>');
      $("#institucion_correo").append('<input type="email" name="f1-institucional" placeholder="Correo electr&oacute;nico institucional..." class="f1-institucional form-control" id="f1-correo-institucional" autocomplete="off">');
      $("#contenido_preguntas").append('<select name="rol" id="seleccionar_rol"><option value="12">Seleccione un rol</option><option value="1">Coordinador SENNOVA</option><option value="2">Asesor SENNOVA</option><option value="3">L&iacute;der SENNOVA</option><option value="4">L&iacute;der de Grupo de Investigaci&oacute;n</option><option value="5">Dinamizador TecnoParque</option><option value="6">Gestor TecnoParque</option><option value="7">L&iacute;der TecnoAcademia</option><option value="8">Facilitador</option><option value="9">L&iacute;der Gesti&oacute;n del Conocimento</option><option value="10">Talento</option><option value="11">Investigador</option></select>');
      $("#contenido_preguntas").append('<br>');
      $("#contenido_preguntas").append('<h4>Seleccione una opci&oacute;n.</h4>');
      $("#contenido_preguntas").append('<br>');
      $("#contenido_preguntas").append('<div class="form-group" id="seleccion_usuario">');
      $("#contenido_preguntas").append('</div>');
      var correo_i = true;
    } else {
      $("#institucion_correo").html('');
      $("#contenido_preguntas").html('');
      $("#contenido_preguntas").html(talentos);
      correo_i = false;
    }
  });

  $('#top-navbar-1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $.backstretch("resize");
  });
  $('#top-navbar-1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $.backstretch("resize");
  });

  /*
      Form
      */
  $('.f1 fieldset:first').fadeIn('slow');

  $('.f1 input[type="text"], .f1 input[type="password"], .f1 input[type="email"], .f1 input[type="number"], .f1 textarea, .f1 select|').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('input-error');
  });

  // next step
  $('.f1 .btn-next').on('click', function() {
    var validar_correo = $("#f1-correo-personal").val();
    var validar_institucion = $("#f1-correo-institucional").val();
    var contrasena_nueva = $("#f1-contrasena-nueva").val();
    var confirmar_contrasena = $("#f1-contrasena-confirmar").val();
    var documento_nuevo = $("#f1-documento").val();

    function validateEmail(validar_correo) {
      var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
      return regex.test(validar_correo);
    }

    function validarEmail(validar_institucion) {
      var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@((misena|sena)+\.+(edu.co))$/;
      return regex.test(validar_institucion);
    }
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    // fields validation
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], textarea, select').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == "12" || $(this).val() == 12) {
        if (validateEmail(validar_correo) != true || validateEmail(validar_correo) == false) {
          $(this).addClass('input-error');
          $("#f1-correo-personal").addClass('input-error');
          next_step = false;

          if (correo_i) {
            if (validateEmail(validar_institucion) != true || validateEmail(validar_institucion) == false) {
              $(this).addClass('input-error');
              $("#f1-correo-institucional").addClass('input-error');
              next_step = false;
            } else {
              $(this).addClass('input-error');
              next_step = false;
            }
          }
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('input-error');
          next_step = false;

          if (correo_i) {
            if (validateEmail(validar_institucion) != true || validateEmail(validar_institucion) == false) {
              $(this).addClass('input-error');
              $("#f1-correo-institucional").addClass('input-error');
              next_step = false;
            } else {
              $(this).addClass('input-error');
              next_step = false;
            }
          }
        }
        next_step = false;
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        if (correo_i) {
          if (validateEmail(validar_correo) == true) {
            if (validarEmail(validar_institucion) == true) {
              if (documento_nuevo > 999999 && documento_nuevo < 99999999999) {
                if (contrasena_nueva == confirmar_contrasena) {
                  next_step = true;
                } else {
                  $("#f1-contrasena-confirmar").addClass('input-error');
                  next_step = false;
                }
              } else {
                $("#f1-contrasena-confirmar").addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
              }
            } else {
              $("#f1-correo-institucional").addClass('input-error');
              next_step = false;
            }
          } else {
            $("#f1-correo-personal").addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
          }
        } else {
          if (validateEmail(validar_correo) == true) {
            if (documento_nuevo > 999999 && documento_nuevo < 99999999999) {
              if (contrasena_nueva == confirmar_contrasena) {
                next_step = true;
              } else {
                $("#f1-contrasena-confirmar").addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
              }
            } else {
              $("#f1-contrasena-confirmar").addClass('input-error');
              next_step = false;
            }
          } else {
            $("#f1-correo-personal").addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
          }
        }
      }
    });
    // fields validation

    if (next_step == true) {
      parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
        // change icons
        current_active_step.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active');
        // progress bar
        bar_progress(progress_line, 'right');
        // show next step
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
        // scroll window to beginning of the form
        scroll_to_class($('.f1'), 20);
      });
    }

  });

  // previous step
  $('.f1 .btn-previous').on('click', function() {
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function() {
      // change icons
      current_active_step.removeClass('active').prev().removeClass('activated').addClass('active');
      // progress bar
      bar_progress(progress_line, 'left');
      // show previous step
      $(this).prev().fadeIn();
      // scroll window to beginning of the form
      scroll_to_class($('.f1'), 20);
    });
  });

  // submit
  $('.f1').on('submit', function(e) {

    // fields validation
    $(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], input[type="number"], textarea, select').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('input-error');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
    });
    // fields validation

  });


});

$(document).on("change", "#seleccionar_regional", function() {
  var region = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "consultas.php",
    data: {
      region: region
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#seleccionar_centro').html(data);
    }
  });
})
$(document).on("click", "#leer_politicas", function(e) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "condiciones.php",
    error: function() {
      alert("Error con la petición AJAX.");
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#observar_politicas").html(data);
    }
  });
});
$(document).on("click", "#aceptar_condiciones", function(e) {
  $("#macro").load("body");
  $("#macro").removeClass('sombreado');
  $("#politicas").remove();
  $("#enviar_registro").removeAttr('disabled');
});

var investigadores = '<label class="sr-only" for="f1-regional">&iquest;A qu&eaacute; regional pertenece?</label><select id="seleccionar_regional" name="seleccionar_regional"><option value="">Regional</option><option value="1">Amazonas</option><option value="2">Antioquia</option><option value="3">Arauca</option><option value="4">Atl&aacute;ntico</option><option value="5">Bogot&aacute;</option><option value="6">Bol&iacute;var</option><option value="6">Boyac&aacute;</option><option value="8">Caldas</option><option value="9">Caquet&aacute;</option><option value="10">Casanare</option><option value="11">Cauca</option><option value="12">Cesar</option><option value="13">Choc&oacute;</option><option value="14">C&oacute;rdoba</option><option value="15">Cundinamarca</option><option value="16">Guain&iacute;a</option><option value="17">Guaviare</option><option value="18">Huila</option><option value="19">La Guajira</option><option value="20">Magdalena</option><option value="21">Meta</option><option value="22">Nari&ntilde;o</option><option value="23">Norte de Santander</option><option value="24">Putumayo</option><option value="25">Quind&iacute;o</option><option value="26">Risaralda</option><option value="27">San Andr&eacute;s y Providencia</option><option value="28">Santander</option><option value="29">Sucre</option><option value="30">Tolima</option><option value="31">Valle del Cauca</option><option value="32">Vaup&eacute;s</option><option value="33">Vichada</option></select><br><select id="seleccionar_centro" name="seleccionar_centro"><option value="">Centro de formaci&oacute;n</option></select>';

var talentos = '<select id="seleccionar_sede" name="seleccionar_sede"><option value="">Sedes TecnoParque</option><option value="1">Valledupar</option><option value="2">Oca&ntilde;a</option><option value="3">Bucaramanga</option><option value="4">Medell&iacute;n</option><option value="5">Rionegro</option><option value="6">Manizales</option><option value="7">Pereira</option><option value="8">Bogot&aacute;</option><option value="9">Cazuc&aacute;</option><option value="10">La Granja</option><option value="11">Cali</option><option value="12">Neiva</option><option value="13">Pitalito</option><option value="14">Angostura</option><option value="15">Socorro</option></select>';

var regionales = '<label class="sr-only" for="f1-regional">&iquest;A qu&eaacute; regional pertenece?</label><select id="seleccionar_regional" name="seleccionar_regional"><option value="">Regional</option><option value="1">Amazonas</option><option value="2">Antioquia</option><option value="3">Arauca</option><option value="4">Atl&aacute;ntico</option><option value="5">Bogot&aacute;</option><option value="6">Bol&iacute;var</option><option value="6">Boyac&aacute;</option><option value="8">Caldas</option><option value="9">Caquet&aacute;</option><option value="10">Casanare</option><option value="11">Cauca</option><option value="12">Cesar</option><option value="13">Choc&oacute;</option><option value="14">C&oacute;rdoba</option><option value="15">Cundinamarca</option><option value="16">Guain&iacute;a</option><option value="17">Guaviare</option><option value="18">Huila</option><option value="19">La Guajira</option><option value="20">Magdalena</option><option value="21">Meta</option><option value="22">Nari&ntilde;o</option><option value="23">Norte de Santander</option><option value="24">Putumayo</option><option value="25">Quind&iacute;o</option><option value="26">Risaralda</option><option value="27">San Andr&eacute;s y Providencia</option><option value="28">Santander</option><option value="29">Sucre</option><option value="30">Tolima</option><option value="31">Valle del Cauca</option><option value="32">Vaup&eacute;s</option><option value="33">Vichada</option></select><br><select id="seleccionar_centro" name="seleccionar_centro"><option value="">Centro de formaci&oacute;n</option></select>';

$(document).on("change", "#seleccionar_rol", function(e) {
  var rol = $(this).val();
  if (rol == "1" || rol == "2" || rol == "5" || rol == "6" || rol == "7" || rol == "8" || rol == "9") {
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('Seleccione una regional.');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").append(investigadores);
  } else if (rol == "3" || rol == "4") {
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('Seleccione una regional y su centro de formaci&oacute;n.');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").append(investigadores);
  } else if (rol == "10") {
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('Seleccione una sede de tecnoparques.');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").append(talentos);
  } else if (rol == "11") {
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('Seleccione una regional y su centro de formaci&oacute;n.');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").append(investigadores);
  } else {
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('');
  }
});

$(document).on("click", "input[type='radio']", function(e) {
  var rol = $(this).val();
  if (rol == 11) {
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('Seleccione una regional y su centro de formaci&oacute;n.');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").append(investigadores);
  } else if (rol == 10) {
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('Seleccione una sede de tecnoparques.');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").append(talentos);
  } else if (rol == 13) {
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").html('Llene este formulario, por favor.');
    $("#seleccion_usuario").append(talentos);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form-box" style="margin:auto;">
      <form role="form" action="registrar.php" method="post" class="f1">
        <h3>REG&Iacute;STRESE EN EL APLICATIVO</h3>
        <p>Diligencie el formulario para tener acceso directo.</p>
        <div class="f1-steps">
          <div class="f1-progress">
            <div class="f1-progress-line" data-now-value="16.66" data-number-of-steps="3" style="width: 16.66%;"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="f1-step active">
            <div class="f1-step-icon"></div>
            <p>Datos b&aacute;sicos</p>
          </div>
          <div class="f1-step">
            <div class="f1-step-icon"></div>
            <p>Datos de lugar</p>
          </div>
          <div class="f1-step">
            <div class="f1-step-icon"></div>
            <p>Introducci&oacute;n</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
          <h4>Ingrese sus datos b&aacute;sicos:</h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only">Tipo de documento</label>
            <select name="f1-tipo-documento" id="f1-tipo-documento">
              <option value="">Seleccione un tipo de documento</option>
              <option value="T.I.">Tarjeta de identidad</option>
              <option value="C.C.">C&eacute;dula de ciudadan&iacute;a</option>
              <option value="C.E.">C&eacute;dula de extranjer&iacute;a</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only">N&uacute;mero de documento</label>
            <input type="number" name="f1-documento" placeholder="N&uacute;mero de documento..." class="f1-documento form-control" id="f1-documento" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-nombres">Nombres</label>
            <input type="text" name="f1-nombres" placeholder="Nombres..." class="f1-nombres form-control" id="f1-nombres" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-apellidos">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" name="f1-apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos..." class="f1-apellidos form-control" id="f1-apellidos" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-contacto">N&uacute;mero de contacto</label>
            <input type="number" name="f1-contacto" placeholder="N&uacute;mero de contacto..." class="f1-contacto form-control" id="f1-contacto" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-correo">Correo electr&oacute;</label>
            <input type="email" name="f1-correo" placeholder="Correo electr&oacute;nico..." class="f1-correo form-control" id="f1-correo-personal" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="position: relative;left: 5%;">
            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-opcionsena">&iquest;Pertenece al SENA?</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="pertenece_sena" id="pertenece_sena">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&iquest;Pertenece al SENA?</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" id="institucion_correo">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-contrasena">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
            <input type="password" name="f1-contrasena" placeholder="Nueva contrase&ntilde;a..." class="f1-contrasena form-control" id="f1-contrasena" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-repetir-contrasena">Repita la contrase&ntilde;a</label>
            <input type="password" name="f1-repetir-contrasena" placeholder="Repita la contrase&ntilde;a que usar&aacute;..." class="f1-repetir-contrasena form-control" id="f1-repetir-contrasena" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="f1-buttons">
            <a href="../"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" id="seguir" style="background-color:#59B548">Siguiente</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>

          <div class="form-group" id="contenido_preguntas">

            <p>Seleccione una sede de TecnoParque con la que se encuentra vinculado(a).</p>

            <select id="seleccionar_sede" name="seleccionar_sede">

              <option value="">Sedes TecnoParque</option>
              <option value="1">Valledupar</option>
              <option value="2">Oca&ntilde;a</option>
              <option value="3">Bucaramanga</option>
              <option value="4">Medell&iacute;n</option>
              <option value="5">Rionegro</option>
              <option value="6">Manizales</option>
              <option value="7">Pereira</option>
              <option value="8">Bogot&aacute;</option>
              <option value="9">Cazuc&aacute;</option>
              <option value="10">La Granja</option>
              <option value="11">Cali</option>
              <option value="12">Neiva</option>
              <option value="13">Pitalito</option>
              <option value="14">Angostura</option>
              <option value="15">Socorro</option>

            </select>

          </div>

          <div class="f1-buttons">

            <a href="../"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Anterior</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" style="background-color:#59B548">Siguiente</button>

          </div>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <h4>Video de introducci&oacute;n:</h4>
          <p>Al hacer click en 'Registrarse', estar&aacute; aceptando nuestra <label id="leer_politicas" style="color:#f35b3f;cursor:pointer;">Pol&iacute;tica de privacidad</label>. Por esto, solicitamos primero los lea para poder proseguir.</p>
          <div class="f1-buttons">
            <a href="../"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Anterior</button>
            <button type="submit" name="final" id="enviar_registro" class="btn btn-submit">Registrarse</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<section id="observar_politicas"></section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/voz.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Este el html y el código JS que uso. Uso el framework de Bootstrap, pero también combino código propio para realizar distintas funciones adjuntas. Estas funciones trabajan correctamente, pero el botón de pasar de un paso a otro no funciona. Intenté agregarle un `console.log` y un `alert`, pero no lo toma.

Comment: Prueba borrar las cookies y el caché de tu navegador.
De igual forma, verifica que tus navegadores estén actualizados.

Comment: El problema no es sólo en mi PC, si no en todos los demás.

Comment: Si no toma cambios como añadir un console.log, el script está en cache. Límpialo / deshabilita el caché para esa página y sigue probando.

Comment: Lo hice, sin embargo no funciona.

Comment: Te sale algo en la consola cuando cargas la página o cuando haces clic en el botón?

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .f1 input[type="text"], .f1 input[type="password"], .f1 input[type="email"], .f1 input[type="number"], .f1 textarea, .f1 select|  Este es el error. Por cierto, en Mozilla me toma la página como no segura.

Comment: Lo de que te cargue la página como no segura se da (entre otras) porque a) usas un certificado que no corresponde al dominio en el que lo estás usando, o b) estás cargando recursos de otros sitios (algo como hotlinking). Veo que jquery en teoría lo tienes local, así que no sería el mismo problema

Comment: Cuando haces `.f1 select|`, tienes un pipe ahí como si fueras a buscar atributos que comiencen por algo, pero parece incompleto. Seguro que va así?

Comment: No uso recursos externos. Todo es descargado. El '|' lo quité y funcionó.

Comment: Era un error tipográfico, entonces :)  Sobre el lío de la página no segura, Firefox suele dar un código de la excepción en los detalles del error. Dependiendo de eso se puede saber qué es lo que no le gusta :)